# How to allow remote connections to mysql from specific IPs only?

Tags: mysql, remote

I have a fresh install of mysql server 5.2.6 on a 64 bit Ubuntu running on a remote server with static IP. Is there anyway to allow Mysql remote connections to be made from pre-approved IPs only? 
I am looking for simple and elegant way to do this without doing too much OS related admin and just handle it with mysql.

Answer (score 11):

You can use hostname in grant statements as well, as you are using shared ip then you can limit it with hostname specific grant such as below

```
grant all on db.* to 'user'@'hostname' identified by 'password';
```

To allow from all IP's/hosts

```
grant all on db.* to 'user'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

For localhost only

```
grant all on db.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not answer to my question

Comment: to check for anonym user, you can try mysql -u<user>. In order to restrict ip access you need to provide ip or hostname in grant statement. you can check your hostname and grant access like that grant all on db.* to 'user'@'hostname' identified by 'password'. Give it a try

Comment: @pythonman did it work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON yourdb.* To your_user@'192.162.1.1' identified by 'password';`

To allow entire intranet, or similar:

`GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON yourdb.* To your_user@'192.162.%' identified by 'password';`

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did but now it is refusing connection from my IP, however i am using a shared ip but not sure if that makes any diffrences

Comment: this is what i put in GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'78.141.189.76' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Access denied for user 'test'@'78.141.189.76' (using password: YES)

Comment: That means 2 possibilities. (1) wrong password. Try resetting password to known one (2) insufficient privileges. Also, do you have an anonymous user? That could have taken precedence over user you created.

Comment: How do I check for the anonym user?

Comment: You can view the privilege of particular database for user. SELECT USER, HOST, db, select_priv, insert_priv, grant_priv FROM mysql.db

Comment: @pythonman, go to 'sql prompt' and type ' show full columns from yourdatabasename.tablename'   it will shows user db permission for particular table & also database.

Comment: @pythonman, The user have only 'select' privilege permission for that database.